# Direct assembly code execution in VBA - only fails in Excel

Tags: vba, assembly, com, x86-64, shellcode

I have some VBA code to swap one of the function pointers in a COM vtable with a NO-OP bit of assembly code. *It works in twinBASIC* which is a standalone VBA environment, so I know I'm very close, however in Excel it crashes.

This is the minrepro, works in tB and in theory not in Excel VBA.

```vb
Class DummyThing
    Sub DoNothing()
    End Sub
End Class

Module VBA
    Private Const MEM_COMMIT As Long = &H1000
    Private Const MEM_RESERVE As Long = &H2000
    Private Const PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE  As Long = &H40

    Declare PtrSafe Function VirtualAlloc Lib "kernel32" ( _
            ByVal lpAddress As LongPtr, _
            ByVal dwSize As Long, _
            ByVal flAllocationType As Long, _
            ByVal flProtect As Long) As LongPtr

    Sub Main()
        Dim code(1 To 4) As Byte
        code(1) = CByte(&h48)    
        code(2) = CByte(&h31)
        code(3) = CByte(&hC0) 'xor rax, rax to clear it - this is like setting the hresult to 0
        code(4) = CByte(&hC3) 'ret

        Dim buffer As LongPtr
        buffer = VirtualAlloc(0&, UBound(code) - LBound(code) + 1, MEM_COMMIT Or MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE)

        If buffer = 0 Then
            Debug.Print "VirtualAlloc() failed (Err:" ; Err.LastDllError ; ")."
            Exit Sub
        End If

        CopyMemory ByVal buffer, code(1), UBound(code) - LBound(code) + 1

        Dim base As DummyThing
        Set base = New DummyThing

        Dim vtable As LongPtr
        vtable = MemLongPtr(ObjPtr(base))

        MemLongPtr(vtable + PTR_SIZE * 7) = buffer

        base.DoNothing 'Excel VBA crashes here, tB prints the message below
        Debug.Print vbNewLine ; "Done!"
    End Sub

End Module
```

<sub>The memory apis come from here https://github.com/cristianbuse/VBA-MemoryTools/blob/master/src/LibMemory.bas</sub>

It is a super simple 64 bit assembly code that runs by swapping the vtable of `Sub DoNothing()` out and replacing it with a pointer to some executable opcodes. The assembly code is nothing more than

```
48 31 C0          xor    rax, rax                ; Set return value to 0
C3                ret                            ; Return
```

What might be causing the crash - maybe VBA checks the vtable integrity and that it points to memory in an expected address range? But I've never had this issue before with overloading vtables.

Comment: Do you use the code you show in your question? If not, why showing only a slice? If yes, it misses some API, Properties declarations (`CopyMemory`, `MemLongPtr`)...

Comment: Is your excel 64 bit?  How about your `twinBASIC`? PS: `xor eax, eax` is enough in 64 bit as well as 32 so you can drop the `48` byte. That has nothing to do with the crash though.

Comment: If decoded in 32-bit mode, `48 31 C0` is `dec eax` / `xor eax, eax`, so even a 32-bit excel wouldn't explain the crash, assuming execution actually reached your machine code.  (e.g. that the vtable layout is the same, etc.)

Comment: @Jester Yes all 64 bit. Nice tip on registers that writes just the lower bits right, which is sufficient for 32 bit hresult?

Comment: @FaneDuru The memory APIs are linked below the code, they are good reliable ones (https://github.com/cristianbuse/VBA-MemoryTools/blob/master/src/LibMemory.bas)

Comment: @Greedo `xor eax, eax` in a 64-bit segment actually does write the full 64 bits of `rax` due to the zero-extension when you write to a 32-bit register.

Comment: @Greedo Apologies for the unrelated comment. I remember you were looking into iterating a private array inside a class using a ```For Each``` loop but I can't find the post anymore. Did you ever figure that out? Thanks!

Comment: @CristianBuse Not sure about private array. I remember you sharing code to flatten a multi dimensional array into a 1D iterable. I have managed that yes, and generator functions to make anything iterable with for each. This question is leading towards creating an assembly code Iunk:: Release to guarantee CoTaskMemFree is called.

Comment: Is this what you were getting at? Implementing IEnumVariant over an array and expose that as a class's iterator. I guess you are talking about a class containing a private variable which is an array. Yes this is certainly possible but currently a memory leak until I figure out the assembly code. It's not public yet for that reason but I can share if needed

Comment: Thanks @Greedo . Yes, I was reffering to a private array member of a class. No need to share now as I wouldn'g have the time to look at it anyway but pleasse do let me know when you manage to make it work - that would be awesome. Thanks!

Comment: [What is the best way to set a register to zero in x86 assembly: xor, mov or and?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33666617) / [Why do x86-64 instructions on 32-bit registers zero the upper part of the full 64-bit register?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11177137)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found an answer

> In VBA64, for classes implemented by VBA, [the interpreter] doesn't use the vtable
> function pointers directly.  Instead, it detects that the object is
> implemented by VBA (itself) and shortcuts to the direct pcode
> implementation of the requested member instead of using the native
> function pointer which has to jump back into the pcode virtual
> machine.  It's an optimization, though in reality it's a
> micro-optimization, but ultimately it prevents simple vtable patching
> from working.
>
> It wasn't always this way.  In the early versions of VBA64 (office
> 2010 without service packs), they did use the native vtable function
> calls, and you could at that time use normal vtable patching.

https://discord.com/channels/927638153546829845/1157647794484543589/1157660431545024553

So the crash comes from VBA seeing the class is a VBA class and then using the pointer from the vtable as a signpost to shortcut into pcode as an optimisation.

Except because we overwrote the function pointer, it doesn't have corresponding pcode in the same place so the lookup fails or VBA starts trying to interpret random memory as pcode leading to the crash.

Solution is invoke the assem without vtable patching to avoid the optimisation - e.g. using dispcallfunc, or by implementing the entire COM object manually with CoTaskMemAlloc and a handcrafted vtable.